# QGraphicsScence stays blank after adding forms

Tags: qt

I want to draw on a QMainWindow: Until now, I have set up a simple project and entered some code into the constructor. The QGraphicsView shows a blank canvas. What else do I have to do to make my drawings visible?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene scene(0,0,800,600);
    this->view.setScene(&scene);
    this->setCentralWidget(&view);
    scene.addText("Hello, world!");
    QPen pen(Qt::green);
    scene.addLine(0,0,200,200,pen);
    scene.addEllipse(400,300,100,100,pen);
    //make a point:
    double rad = 1;
    scene.addEllipse(10-rad, 10-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0,pen,QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
    scene.update();
    view.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsScene scene` is a local variable of `MainWindow` constructor.  Once constructor ended, the variable is destroyed, which leads to undefined behavior when the view tries to access the scene.  Your program may crash.

Make it a member variable of the `MainWindow` class and initialize with `new` in constructor.  Or at least try `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,800,600,this)`, it will get deleted by Qt when `MainWindow` is destroyed.

Comment: oooouuch. I thought the scene would be kept alive since I added it to the view.

Comment: The pointer to it will be kept since you passed it, but the actual object is destroyed.  Qt cannot override C++ memory management for automatic variables.